# Can the Unity File Lens display detailed file information?

Tags: unity, lenses, previews

Is it possible to make Unity File Lens to display synthetic information about the files recalled by a search? It would be very useful, for example, if it could display the location, the size and the date of the file...

Answer (score 0):

Yes - in Unity 6.6 above, which will be in Ubuntu 12.10, and has arrived in the development distribution.  The new feature is called Previews; I like it already, and it has a ton of potential, for things like quick web search results, in the future.  You right click on the item in the Dash to get a Preview.

Here's a screenshot of a file preview: [image: file previewed in the Dash].

And [here's an article about them with more info](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/say-hello-to-unitys-newest-feature-previews).  (Previews are in Quantal now,not just in a PPA as when then article was written.)

I think new additions to the Dash also mean Lenses can have another line or two of info, under an item in the big grid.  That might mean someone could add more file info to the lens before you preview one item.  It would probably be too cluttered for the main file lens, so this imaginary feature might have to be in some kind of add-on, or a separate file-management type of lens.